# XSL - Get attribute of previous element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In the `if` block below I want to be also test whether `@Timestamp` is smaller than the previous `Message`'s timestamp.  How can I achieve this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Message">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newclass">
        <xsl:if test="@Timestamp + 60 &gt; $ctimestamp">new</xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tr><td class="debugtime">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Time"/>
    </td><td class="{$newclass}">
        <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
    </td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Example XML

```
<Message Time="2010/06/17 04:23:32" Timestamp="1276773812">message1</Message>
<Message Time="2010/06/17 04:23:32" Timestamp="1276773812">message2</Message>
<Message Time="2010/06/17 04:23:33" Timestamp="1276773813">message3</Message>
<Message Time="2010/06/17 04:23:33" Timestamp="1276773813">message4</Message>
```

Update:
I have implemented both variations of the current answers but to no luck.  It always doesn't seem to work properly for the second elements onwards, in that it will bold the first correctly but no more (although sometimes it will do the third).  Updated `if` block code below.

```
<xsl:if test="@Timestamp + 60 &gt; $ctimestamp">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        new
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1 and ../Message[position()-1]/@Timestamp - 1 &lt; @Timestamp">
        new
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @Chris: post some XML input document, please.

Comment: If you are providing my block of code the example xml you provided, then that is the desired behavior, output on first, and third. look at timestamp change.

also, what is the value of $ctimestamp?

Comment: Beg your pardon, I want `<=` behaviour and added a -1 (as reflected in the new updated code above) but missed it out when doing the initial update.

Comment: You seem to have problems explaining what you want. What is the "-1" in your code supposed to do? In the XML fragment there is *no* node with a timestampl lesser than any of the previous nodes! What are you talking about???

Comment: In the example XML there are 4 nodes, 2 nodes have a timestamp of 1276773812 and the other two 1276773813 (one second later).  The -1 is because I was unsure how to do `<=` in XSL so I simulated the effect by taking 1 away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Timestamp &lt; preceding-sibling::Message[1]/@Timestamp
```

Comment: Forgot about XPath Axeses,

but perhaps it should be

@Timestamp &lt; preceding-sibling::Message[position()+1]/@Timestamp

depending on what XPath chooses to give us.

Comment: Please see my update, I tried your implementation as well as the one currently listed in my updated code.  I also tried @Meiscooldude's variation

Comment: Thanks Max - This seems to alternately bold every other line i.e. 1,3,5,7 etc

Comment: Ah... got it working with `following-sibling` as opposed to `preceeding-sibling` - thanks

Comment: @Chris: I don't understand, I thought you wanted to compare with the previous Message, why are you using `following-sibling` ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this solution, but this should do you.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Message">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newclass">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
         <xsl:if test="..\Message[position()-1]@Timestamp &lt; @Timestamp">new</xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
         new
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

   <tr><td class="debugtime">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Time"/>
   </td><td class="{$newclass}">
       <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
   </td></tr>

</xsl:for-each>
```